# Prove that if $A$ is a square matrix such that $A^4$ = $0$ , then the matrices $A - I $ and $A^3 + A^2 + A + I$ are inverses of each other.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Edit: I took this question from an old exam so as others suggested there may be a typo in the statement.

Can somebody please check over my proof/matrix algebra because I've gone over it several times and don't see where I went wrong.

We must show that

$(A-I)(A^3+A^2+A+I) = I $

Distributing we get,

$AA^3 + AA^2 + AA + AI -IA^3 -IA^2 -IA -II = I $

$A^4 + A^3 + A^2 + A -A^3 -A^2 -A -I = I$

$ 0 - I = I$

$-I = I$

Obviously $ -I \neq I$ so if someone could tell me where I went wrong it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this means what you are trying to prove is actually false. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have the right idea but I would *really* refrain from putting $=I$ on the right hand side. You are trying to show (or not) that it is the identity. Throwing it on the right hand side only makes it a bit confusing and can easily throw you off track. So without that you have:

\begin{align} (A-I)(A^3 + A^2 + A + I) = A^4 + A^3 + A^2 + A - A^3 - A^2 - A - I = -I\end{align}

as you showed. It is definitely incorrect and there is a typo. My guess is they meant $I-A$.

Answer (score 4):

Your calculation is correct. We have
$$-I = A^4 - I = (A - I)(A^3 + A^2 + A + I).$$
So $I - A$ and $A^3 + A^2 + A + I$ are inverses of each other.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this statement is true. If you plug in $A = 0$, then $-I$ is the inverse of $I$. This is a valid counterexample to disprove it.

But it might hold if you change $A - I$ to $I - A$.